# Can I upload music to Google music on Linux?

Tags: linux, music, google-music

I have a Linux CentOS system.

Is there any way to upload music from the command line to Google Music?

Answer (score 7):

[You can now.](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/07/22/better-late-than-never-google-music-manager-now-available-for-linux/)

> ...Google finally released an uploader designed just for Linux.
>
> The uploader essentially works just like the Windows version, with one
>   small tweak: OGG support. OGG files will automatically be transcoded
>   to 320kbps MP3 files, which will inevitably make the already painfully
>   slow uploading process last even longer -- but hey, at least you can
>   finally use that beta invite, right?
>
> To grab the uploader, head over to the Google Music Landing page, hit
>   'Download the Music Manager', select the appropriate package based on
>   your Linux distro, and install.

Comment: Link-only posts are discouraged at SU, as the link may die in the future.  Please provide pertinent information in your answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you appear to be looking for is https://github.com/thebigmunch/gmusicapi-scripts - a set of python scripts to upload, download or bi-directionally sync tracks. This, in turn, draws from https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API should you wish to use these python libraries for your own projects.

I've just provided this exact same answer to "[uploading music automatically with Google Music on a Linux server](https://superuser.com/q/703168/384286)"

Answer (score 2):

No, you need Google Music Manager which isn't on Linux yet, unfortunately.

However [this guy](http://antimatter15.com/wp/2011/05/uploading-mp3s-to-google-music-beta-from-linux-chrome-os-win-and-mac/) did have a way to upload from linux (apart from using wine) but ever since the "hack" he used got patched it stopped working. In his most recent comment he writes `"Now the only way to upload that i’m aware of is by sending that protobuf encoded https post to a certain site."`

eh. Maybe someone else knows, but it'd probably be easiest to wait for Google.